# Get enum properties in annotation processor

Tags: java, enums, annotation-processing

I want to generate a Javascript object for each of my JAVA enums with their properties.

For example for this enum :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum ETypeModel {
  TYPE_I("Type modèle 1", 10),
  TYPE_II("Type modèle 2", 20);

  @Getter private String label;
  @Getter private int priority;
}
```

I would like to generate a JS file similar to :

```
const ETypeModel = {
    TYPE_I : {label: 'Type modèle 1', priority: 10},
    TYPE_II: {label: 'Type modèle 2', priority: 20}
};
```

So I created an annotation processor, for now I am able to list the values of the enum (TYPE_I and TYPE_II) but I don't know how to get the properties for each values (label and priority).

My current processor :

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"fr.mistic.TsExportable"})
public class TsExportableProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

@Override
public boolean process(final Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, final RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
    if (!roundEnvironment.processingOver()) {
        for (final Element element : roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(TsExportable.class)) {
            handleElement(element);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void handleElement(final Element element) {
    if (ElementKind.ENUM.equals(element.getKind())) {
        handleEnum(element);
    }
}

void handleEnum(final Element element) {
    List<Element> values = element.getEnclosedElements()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKind().equals(ElementKind.ENUM_CONSTANT))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    log(element.getSimpleName().toString()); // Prints ETypeModel
    values.forEach(e -> {
        log(e.toString()); // Prints TYPE_I and TYPE_II
    });
}

void log(String str) {
    processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, str);
}

}
```

Comment: This may be something better suited for a transpiler.

Comment: @killjoy Do you have any hints ? I found JSweet but it's clearly overkill for what I want.

Comment: @Mistic, did you ever figure out how to get the enum values (eg "Type modèle 1", 10) via  annotation processing? I'm trying to do the same thing.